# What is the difference between i2c-dev and i2c-bcm2708

Tags: i2c

I have been trying to figure out how to use i2c on RaspberryPi, and the What is the difference between i2c-dev and i2c-bcm2708 mentioned [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1190/how-to-make-raspbian-load-the-i2c-dev-module-on-boot-up)? I would assume the i2c-bcm2708 module is specific to the RaspberryPi's ARM processor, so then why should I also install the i2c-dev module?

Comment: [This article](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/840/why-is-the-cpu-sometimes-referred-to-as-bcm2708-sometimes-bcm2835) helped me immensely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i2c-bcm2708 is the low level driver. i2c-dev creates the convenient `/dev/` entries