# SPI vs 8-bit TFT

Tags: display, video, screen, media, lcd

I read that 8-bit is faster than SPI, how much faster is 8-bit than SPI?

Say, if I wanted to run a video loop of a wheel spinning, would the speed difference between SPI and 8-bit mode be obvious?

Comment: There's no good answer to this question... "how much faster?"  ... It depends on many factors.  In general, it is faster to read and write a full byte at a time rather than place data in a shift register and output it one bit at a time synchronized with a clock signal.  If the clock is the same frequency on both the serial interface and the parallel interface (8-bit), then the data rate on the parallel might be effectively 8 times the serial rate... However, implementation limitations need to be considered.... "Video of a spinning wheel" ... what is the desired frame rate, res? SPI clock OK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are talking about connecting a display on the GPIO of the PI.

**GPIO bandwidth**

Here are some speed benchmarks for the GPIOS: [github page](https://github.com/hzeller/rpi-gpio-dma-demo), and one can toggle a GPIO on the PI 3 at **65.8Mhz**.

This is the speed for toggling one bit. If you want to drive a 8-bit parallel bus, you will need to drive the 8-bits of data + the control bits (at least the write signal), so you will probably need to write one more register in every loop, reducing the speed by 33% -> **~43.8 MHz**. So the maximum theoretical bandwith is ~43.8 MB/s.

**SPI bandwidth**

According to this [answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/3444/63359), the SPI can run at 125 MHz, giving a maximum bandwidth of **15.625 MB/s** (125/8 bits).

**Bandwidth conclusion**

The GPIO method using one full core at 100% can be almost 3 times faster than the SPI, but since the SPI is driven by DMA, it will use  much less CPU.

On a Rapsberry PI 2, the gain will be slightly less, and on a Raspberry PI 1 it will even be slower than the SPI.

**(Real) conclusion**

If you really need a video output, all Raspberry PI except the zero have  a [DSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_Serial_Interface) connector, which is really the better way of connecting a display to it (the software and the hardware already exist).