# What is the maximum usable SPI frequency for Raspberry Pi 3 Compute Module?

Tags: spi

I have checked [What SPI frequencies does Raspberry Pi support?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/699/what-spi-frequencies-does-raspberry-pi-support) question, anyway its subject is RPi, not RPi Compute module.

Also, I want to check for **usable** frequency, not theoretical. Limitations on 'normal' RPi are probably due to design and despite 125MHz claimed theoretical speed, only 32MHz speed is achievable in practice.

This place https://elinux.org/index.php?title=RPi_SPI#Speed_2 brings the info about max speed of 32MHz

Additionaly,I would also be happy if anybody could mention about any other SBC's with usable SPI frequency speed above 32MHz.

Comment: I believe that using high frequencies would need careful wiring and design.  Given that you haven't mentioned this factor I suspect you won't be able to achieve high frequencies.

Comment: Could you add some context of why you need SPI with clocks above 32MHz? I suspect you're trying to do something that will not go well. There's a reason why high-speed standards like USB are not using SPI internally.